# Workaround for __lookupGetter__ and __lookupSetter__ functions in Google Chrome/Webkit?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, getter-setter

Code depending on the `__lookupGetter__` and `__lookupSetter__` methods are [broken in Google Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=13175) for native objects. This is a hindrance when writing an extension.

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Is there any reason why you need to change them? How about using wrappers?

Comment: I need to intercept document.cookie if cookie isolation is activated in a tab and call the original cookie getter/setter if it is disabled. The get/set of document.cookie is used in a web page context. For example gmail uses it and I need to return my own cookie storage to them.

Comment: intercepting document.cookie sounds like a great way to steal cookies.

Answer (score 0):

`__lookupGetter__` is non-standard, so it's not "broken" to only partially support it.

Comment: I think it is broken because those functions exists and return 'undefined'.

Comment: @sw., since it's non-standard, it's up to them how to support it if at all.